# TestCafe: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

When running Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04.  Using the Alpine node container, I've attempted doing something like this below.

I'm getting the message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at /var/jenkins_home/workspace/LP_Sandbox_EricTestsPiplineCmds/node_modules/browserstack-local/lib/Local.js:57:50
```

[Note:  I believe I've adhered to what was reported in this Github issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack/issues/27)

Here's the pipeline snippet I'm using.  Any help is much welcome.
Thanks in advance!

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:8.11.3-alpine' }
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test') {
            steps {

                sh '''
                    node --version
                    npm install testcafe testcafe-reporter-xunit
                    npm install testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack
                    export BROWSERSTACK_USE_AUTOMATE=1
                    export BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=XXXX
                    export BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=YYYYY
                    export BROWSERSTACK_PARALLEL_RUNS=33
                    ./node_modules/.bin/testcafe "browserstack:chrome@67.0:OS X High Sierra" -S -s $WORKSPACE/screenshots tests/lp.js -e --parallel-runs=33 -r xunit:res.xml
                    '''
            }
        }

    }
```

EDIT:  I think I am able to reproduce this locally using these steps running docker: My steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/thomasleveil/docker-testcafe.git`
2. Modify the Dockerfile to add: `testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack \` to the list of nom packages
3. add these environment variables:

   - `ENV BROWSERSTACK_USE_AUTOMATE=1`
   - `ENV BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=XXXX`
   - `ENV BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX`
   - `ENV BROWSERSTACK_PARALLEL_RUNS=1`
4. Build the docker image  following the `Building the docker image` steps in the README.
5. Run `docker run --rm -it -v /Users/esherman/Code/testcafe_lp:/testcafe_lp tomdesinto/testcafe:latest testcafe "browserstack:chrome@67.0:OS X High Sierra" '/testcafe_lp/tests/*.js' -e`
6. After step 3, the same error occurs.  Hope it’s helpful!

Comment: Would you please clarify whether you see this error message during the module installation or when executing your test?

Comment: Ah, Sorry.  The issue happens at test execution time.

Comment: TestCafe may raise a similar error when a web page has JS errors. To check this, please open your page in a browser and enable the browser console (press F12 for this). If there are JS errors there, you can either fix them on your website or skip them during testing using the -e or --skip-js-errors option(http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors)
Please let me know your results.

Comment: Thanks!  I need to circle back around on this.  I used up all of my browserstack minutes.
Mainly it's not omitting the `-e`, it seemed like a connection issue between my docker container and BrowserStack.  I'll add more to this when I can find out more.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricSherman Let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I am good at the moment.  You can close this ticket for now and I can open a new one if issues come back.  Thanks!